# Excel color retrive with drop down list

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, colors, data-validation

I created an excel file with details of Cyprus League teams.

I made a drop down list with these teams in a sheet named `teams`.

I colored each team with its official color.

I have a separate sheet named `rounds`. When I select two teams for example it does not come with the color as created. Any idea of how to retrieve color also?

Below is a sample picture of what i mean:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I would conditionally format the cells with the pull-downs so that the background color would match the colors of the source cells.

Comment: Define the colors within the conditional formatting box as opposed to manually setting the color of cells on the sheet

Answer (score 0):

I would use conditional formatting to accomplish this.  I created a sample to show you.  If your list of teams look like this
[image: Team List]

Then you could add rules using conditional formatting to color as you need
[image: Conditional FOrmatting]

And add as many parameters you wish
[image: Add Colors]

Comment: hi, i already did this.
i was wondering if i can retrieve the cell as it is. thanks for your effort

Comment: Can you use Conditional formatting on the destination workbook as well?

Comment: yes i  can use this also